# Exception when converting date from angular4 to java using dozer

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, dozer

I'm using rest service using angular4 and spring

I send a json object with date field like this   `"startDate": "2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"`

I'm using dozer for mapping and I got this exception

```
"text": "org.dozer.converters.ConversionException: Unable to parse source object using specified date format\r\n\tat org.dozer.converters.DateConverter.convert(DateConverter.java:74)\r\n\tat org.dozer.converters.PrimitiveOrWrapperConverter.convert(PrimitiveOrWrapperConverter.java:69)\r\n\tat org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:418)\r\n\tat
```

Comment: change `"startDate": "2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"` to `"startDate": "2018-02-22T00:00:00Z"`

Comment: thanks, I got the same exception

Comment: do you have any `xml` file for mapping?

Comment: yes but I dont do any configuration for my objects I dont know if I should specify date-format in <mapping> tag

Comment: please share xml file

Comment: I dont have any configuration I have it just in the case if I will sue it :)

Comment: use this : `"startDate": "2018-02-22 00:00:00"`